# Have a number correspond to a position in a multi dimensional array (map 1D numeric values to 2D)

Tags: c#

I would like the user to input a number 1-9 and have that number correspond to a position on a 3x3 2d array. And then change the value in that array to an "x".

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

string[,] numbers = { 
                    { " ", " ", " " },
                    { " ", " ", " " }, 
                    { " ", " ", " " }
                    };
```

At first I decided to do this:

```
int x = input % 3 - 1;
int y = input / 3 - 1;
```

And then access the array at `numbers[y, x]` however this caused problems with the index being out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, sure. Just get the math right

Comment: Think about what `y` values you get for `input` 1 or 2

Comment: Make a table from 1 to 9. Write down the expected x and y values. Then think about a formula which calculates each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a somewhat good intuition for subtracting 1, but you did it in a wrong way.

The correct would be:

```
int x = (input-1) % 3;
int y = (input-1) / 3;
```

Subtracting 1 from the `input` (in the range 1..9) will translate it to the range **0..8**.
Then using `/` and `%` with 3, will get you the `x`,`y` coordinates, both in **0..2** range.

Comment: A bit more accurate code is `.. % numbers.GetLength(0);` without magic constants (`3`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I agree. You can also make it more general by parametrizing the width and height of the matrix (i.e. do not assume it is squared) and the input range. But I'll leave that for the OP to generelize if needed.